# How to get common prefix of strings in a list

Tags: python, string, prefix

I need to know how to identify prefixes in strings in a list. For example,

```
list = ['nomad', 'normal', 'nonstop', 'noob']
```

Its answer should be 'no' since every string in the list starts with 'no'

I was wondering if there is a method that iterates each letter in strings in the list at the same time and checks each letter is the same with each other.

Comment: Do you mean the longest common word?

Comment: the longest common word at the start of each string

Comment: A google search for [longest common prefix python](https://www.google.com/search?lr=&hl=en&as_qdr=all&q=longest+common+prefix+python&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjhx4LlprLpAhX_IzQIHd2dD5cQ1QIoAHoECA0QAQ) may help (if that's what you mean).

Comment: then the output should be False

Comment: so if the list has ['string, 'strawberry', 'start'], then it should return 'st'

Comment: Try to implement the answer from https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/145757
tried it and it works!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [os.path.commonprefix](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.commonprefix) it will do exactly what you want.

```py
In [1]: list = ['nomad', 'normal', 'nonstop', 'noob']

In [2]: import os.path as p

In [3]: p.commonprefix(list)
Out[3]: 'no'
```

As an aside, naming a list "list" will make it impossible to access the `list` class, so I would recommend using a different variable name.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a code without libraries:

```
for i in range(len(l[0])):
    if False in [l[0][:i] == j[:i] for j in l]:
        print(l[0][:i-1])
        break
```

gives output:

```
no
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in function to do this. If you are looking for short python code that can do this for you, here's my attempt:

```py
def longest_common_prefix(words):
    i = 0
    while len(set([word[:i] for word in words])) <= 1:
        i += 1
    return words[0][:i-1]
```

Explanation: `words` is an iterable of strings. The list comprehension

```py
[word[:i] for word in words]
```

uses string slices to take the first `i` letters of each string. At the beginning, these would all be empty strings. Then, it would consist of the first letter of each word. Then the first two letters, and so on.

Casting to a `set` removes duplicates. For example, `set([1, 2, 2, 3]) = {1, 2, 3}`. By casting our list of prefixes to a set, we remove duplicates. If the length of the set is less than or equal to one, then they are all identical.

The counter `i` just keeps track of how many letters are identical so far.

We return `words[0][i-1]`. We arbitrarily choose the first word and take the first `i-1` letters (which would be the same for any word in the list). The reason that it's `i-1` and not `i` is that `i` gets incremented before we check if all of the words still share the same prefix.

Comment: This code hangs if all of the input words are the same.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fun one:

```
l = ['nomad', 'normal', 'nonstop', 'noob']

def common_prefix(lst):
    for s in zip(*lst):
        if len(set(s)) == 1:
            yield s[0]
        else:
            return

result = ''.join(common_prefix(l))
```

Result:

```
'no'
```

To answer the spirit of your question - `zip(*lst)` is what allows you to "iterate letters in every string in the list at the same time".  For example, `list(zip(*lst))` would look like this:

```
[('n', 'n', 'n', 'n'), ('o', 'o', 'o', 'o'), ('m', 'r', 'n', 'o'), ('a', 'm', 's', 'b')]
```

Now all you need to do is find out the common elements, i.e. the `len` of `set` for each group, and if they're common (`len(set(s)) == 1`) then join it back.

---

As an aside, you probably don't want to call your list by the name `list`. Any time you call `list()` afterwards is gonna be a headache. It's bad practice to shadow built-in keywords.